# How to initialize AASSET_Manager on SDL android app

Tags: c++, android-ndk, sdl-2, android-studio-3.0

How do i use assetmanager.h from an SDL android app from android studio? Do i have to edit SDL_Activity.java? With what?
Calling the functions from assetmanager.h crashes the app. Someone then commented that i need to get the java object or something along those lines before using the API.

I've been trying for weeks without success...
Aassetmager_openDir will crash the app on Android. 
I have already added the -landroid to the mk file...
C++, on Android studio and using the SDL2 library...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just load assets packed into .apk?

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of files in the directory... dirent.h doesn't work on android(OS file access restrictions) but works on windows